# Logback encoder layout for processing output of org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler

Tags: playframework, slf4j, logback, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3

I am using Play 2.3 to develop an application and has enabled netty log wire using `-Dhttp.netty.log.wire=true` when starting up the play application. I have also set the `level="DEBUG"` of the logger `org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler` in a custom `logger.xml` file which I have added to the `conf` directory of the Play application. Next I wanted to take the log messages from this logger to a file with a rolling policy. For this, I have the following configuration in my `logger.xml` file.

```
<configuration>

    <conversionRule conversionWord="coloredLevel" converterClass="play.api.Logger$ColoredLevel" />

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender"> 
        <encoder> 
            <pattern>
                %coloredLevel %logger{15} - %message%n%xException{5}
            </pattern> 
        </encoder> 
    </appender>

    <appender name="ACCESS_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>/Users/bathiyap/Drive/logs/access.log</file>
        <!-- daily rollover with compression -->
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>access-log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.gz</fileNamePattern>
            <!-- keep 1 week worth of history -->
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>
                %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} %message%n
            </pattern>
            <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <!-- additivity=false ensures access log data only goes to the access log -->
    <logger name="org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ACCESS_FILE"/>
    </logger>

    <logger name="play" level="INFO" /> 
    <logger name="application" level="DEBUG" />

    <root level="ERROR">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

As seen from the above configurations all log messages from the `org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler` are sent to `access.log` file while all other log messages are simply written to `STDOUT`. Everything is working as expected with this configuration and all the HTTP request/response related log messages are getting logged in the `access.log` file.

But now my problem is, the log messages in the `access.log` file are too much verbose and the events corresponding to the same request/response goes into multilines. I can understand that this is happening due to the `encoder` block I have specified in the `logger.xml` for the rolling file appender as below.

```
<encoder>
    <pattern>
        %date{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ} %message%n
    </pattern>
    ...
</encoder>
```

I have seen in the logback documentation that we can specify a `layout` class for the `encoder` as below,

```
<encoder class="ch.qos.logback.core.encoder.LayoutWrappingEncoder">
    <layout class="some layout class">
        <pattern>
            a pattern definition matching the layout class
        </pattern>
    </layout>
</encoder>
```

Now the question I have is, are there any standard `layout` classes in Logback for the logger that I am using which generates the log messages, namely, `org.jboss.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler`?

I want each log event (i.e. HTTP request/response) to nicely compact into a single line in the log file in a format such as give below,

```
#RemoteIP:Port #LocalIP:Port #DateTimeStamp #ElapsedTime #RequestMethod #RequestURI #StatusCode #BytesSent #UserAgent
```

Where,

`#RemoteIP:Port` - Remote IP address and Port

`#LocalIP:Port` - Local IP address and Port

`#DateTimeStamp` - Date and Timestamp such as 2015-06-12 00:06:44

`#ElapsedTime` - The time taken to serve the request such as 0.231

`#RequestMethod` - Request method such as GET, POST

`#RequestURI` - Requested URI such as /openapi-rest-web/v1/product/1467866?skuDetail=true

`#StatusCode` - Response status code such as 200

`#BytesSent` - Response's content length such as 3167

`#UserAgent` - Remote user agent such as ""Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.4; Nexus 5 Build/KTU84P)"

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We followed that Action.Simple approach to solve the problem. You have call the action in your controller with following annotation @With(LogAction.class)

```
@Override
  public F.Promise<Result> call(Http.Context ctx) throws Throwable {
  Http.Request request = ctx.request();
  Date curDate = new Date();
  SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("d/EEE/yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
  F.Promise<Result> call = delegate.call(ctx);
  return call.map(r -> {

      accessLogger.info(request.remoteAddress() +
              "- ["+format.format(curDate)+"] "+ request.method() +
              " "+ request.uri() + " " + r.status());      

      return r;
  });
}}
```

Also in the application-logger.xml change the pattern to just the message since we also wanted to format the time.

```
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%message%n</pattern>
        <!-- this quadruples logging throughput -->
    </encoder>
```